# What is the right way to check if glClipControlEXT supported in an Android OpenGLES app?

Tags: android, opengl-es

How do I check if I can call `glClipControlEXT` in an Android OpenGLES app?

For example:

```
glClipControlEXT(GL_LOWER_LEFT_EXT, GL_ZERO_TO_ONE_EXT);
```

Should I enumerate all the extensions (as it done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70545666/2394762))?

```
GLint no_of_extensions = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS, &no_of_extensions);

std::set<std::string> ogl_extensions;
for (int i = 0; i < no_of_extensions; ++i)
    ogl_extensions.insert((const char*)glGetStringi(GL_EXTENSIONS, i));
```

and find `"EXT_clip_control"`?

And how do I get the address of `glClipControlEXT` function?

**EDIT1:**

Tried to add the following to CMake:

```
add_definitions(-DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES=1)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE GLESv2)
```

and was able to compile

```
glClipControlEXT(GL_LOWER_LEFT_EXT, GL_ZERO_TO_ONE_EXT);
```

in my app, but got linker error:

```
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: glClipControlEXT
```

**EDIT2:**

Another alternative:

```
PFNGLCLIPCONTROLEXTPROC myClipControlEXT = (PFNGLCLIPCONTROLEXTPROC)eglGetProcAddress("glClipControlEXT");

myClipControlEXT(GL_LOWER_LEFT_EXT, GL_ZERO_TO_ONE_EXT);

//wglGetProcAddress(“glBlendEquation”)

GLenum tempClipOrigin, tempClipDepth;
glGetIntegerv(GL_CLIP_ORIGIN_EXT, (GLint *)&tempClipOrigin);
glGetIntegerv(GL_CLIP_DEPTH_MODE_EXT, (GLint *)&tempClipDepth);

qDebug() << "GL_CLIP_ORIGIN: " << tempClipOrigin << ", GL_CLIP_DEPTH_MODE: " << tempClipDepth;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I enumerate all the extensions ... and find `EXT_clip_control`?

Yes

> How do I get the address of the `glClipControlEXT` function?

`eglGetProcAccess("glClipControlEXT");`

> How do I check if I can call glClipControlEXT ...

In general it doesn't seem that widely supported. https://opengles.gpuinfo.org/listextensions.php says its available on 17% of reported devices, although looking at the list most recent ones do.